# Autoclose fullscreen of player on iphone

Tags: jquery, ios, iphone, youtube, video.js

I am trying for last two days to autoclose the full screen of video js player when video ends on iPhone but to no success. I am passing a youtube video into my video js player. The same code runs on my laptop properly. I came to know that iPhone plays the video on it's native player in place of video js player I am using. Please guide me how to autoclose the full screen on iPhone. I have tried each and every thing for this. 
Here is the link: http://radiations3.com/videojs_hd_plugin/Hussnain/youtube.html

```
<body>
  <video id="vid1" src="" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="360">
  </video>

  <script type="text/javascript">
         videojs('vid1', { "techOrder": ["youtube"], "src": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jofNR_WkoCE" });

         var id = document.getElementById("vid1");
         var myPlayer = videojs("vid1");
         videojs("vid1").ready(function(){
                 this.on("ended", function(){ 
                 alert("hello");
                  myPlayer.exitFullScreen();
            });
        });     
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`exitFullscreen()`](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#exitfullscreen) with a lowercase `s`.